# A proposition about limit points and isolated points.

Tags: general-topology

I am reading a general topology book written by Osamu Takenouchi.

> Theorem 3:
>   $\overline{A}$ is the minimum closed set which contains $A$.

I found his proof of the above theorem was not correct. But if I can prove the following proposition below, I can correct his error.

Please prove the following proposition.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.
Let $a$ be a limit point of $A$. ( $a$ is a point of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $(B(a ; \epsilon) - \{a\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$ for any positive real number $\epsilon$.)
Let $\epsilon$ be a positive real number.
Let $B(a ; \epsilon)$ be an open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Prove that $B(a ; \epsilon)$ contains a point $b$ which is not equal to $a$ and is not an isolated point of $A$.

Comment: Definition of limit points.

Comment: Thank you very much, xbh.

Comment: You are welcome. Seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Proposition is not correct:

Consider $A=\{1/n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}\subset \Bbb{R}$. Then $0$ is the only limit point of $A$ but no $B(0,\epsilon)$ contains such $b$ as you claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much Indrajit Ghosh for your nice answer.

Comment: @tchappyha Welcome....